# Nextjs Deployment static js files throws 404?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, amazon-cloudfront, next.js13, strapi

We have deployed nextjs in kubernetes cluster during deployment time of rolling update we are getting 404 for all js file inside /_next/static/* path But after deployment issue got fixed there are no 404

And another thing to add is we are in migration phase from wordpress to nextjs so we route all request through cloudfront this is behavior we usually use /_next/static/* to route traffic

I have try to changing dockerfile and added gracetime to pod but non of them have worked